# Unable to use SPIFFS

Tags: arduino, esp32, spiffs

I'm working with Arduino and an ESP32 board. I need to write some files in my ESP32.
but the problem is, SPIFFS doesn't work anymore. I don't know why... It worked till the day before yesterday.

But now when I use SPIFFS_Test from Arduino-Examples or this code:

```
#include "SPIFFS.h"


void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);

  if (!SPIFFS.begin(true)) {
    Serial.println("An Error has occurred while mounting SPIFFS");
    return;
  }

  File file = SPIFFS.open("/test.txt", FILE_WRITE);

  if (!file) {
    Serial.println("There was an error opening the file for writing");
    return;
  }

  if (file.print("TEST")) {
    Serial.println("File was written");
  } else {
    Serial.println("File write failed");
  }

  file.close();

  Serial.println(SPIFFS.exists("/test.txt"));
  Serial.println(SPIFFS.exists("/nonexisting.txt"));

}

void loop() {}
```

I just get the "FAILED ERROR."
What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

I checked the directory and found some files that I created before.
I deleted them and it works again!